# How to display topics using Kafka Clients in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
public static void main(String [] args){

Properties config = new Properties();

config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSRAP._SERVERS_CONFIG, "mybroker.ip.address:9092");

AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(config);
ListTopicsResult ltr = admin.listTopics().names().get();

}
```

I am catching an ExecutionException with the error messages: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName:listTopics, deadlineMs=1599813311360, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372034707292162) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)

StackTrace points to the class KafkaFutureImpl in wrapAndThrow.

I can't really paste the entire error since I am writing all of this through my mobile phone.

I am using Kafka Clients 2.6.0, JDK 1.8.0_191

this is very weird since the timeout happens instantly, and I have also tried passing arguments into get(time, timeunit) and I am getting the same result.

EDIT:
I was missing some dependencies in the POM. That resolved the issue.

Comment: Strange - I tried out your example with v2.5.0 and it worked out of the box. But I noticed, your get() call to the listTopics().names() returns ListTopicsResult whereas mine returns a Set<String>. Are you sure your broker is accessible on given hostname/port?

Comment: I am 100% sure this broker is accessible.

Comment: Is your example compiling in your setup? I now updated to KafkaClients v2.6.0 and still this Line ListTopicsResult ltr = admin.listTopics().names().get(); does not compile (names().get() returns Set<String> and not ListTopicsResult)

Comment: You say in your question EDIT "I was missing some dependencies in the POM". What dependencies were missing?